# Area Weighted Average Grid Interpolation

Tags: python, numpy, scipy, spatial-interpolation

I would like to resize an n-dimensional grid similar to `scipy.ndimage.affine_transform`.
For the stake of simplicity, I describe my problem with the 2-Dimensional case.

I need to downsample an image with an arbitrary non integer factor by more than 2 in both directions. The area of a new pixel represents more than the 4 neighbors (more than 2 in each axis). The resulting value should be a weighted average, for which the partially contained boarder pixels are only partially included in the average.

`affine_transform` with order=1 does bilinear interpolation and only considers the two closest pixels.

Is there a method (e.g. scipy) doing exactly that which I've overlooked?

Thank you in advance.

Comment: Look at https://pillow.readthedocs.io/en/stable/handbook/concepts.html#filters  also https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/image-resizing+python